Как правильно разделить логику между контроллерами с usecases?
Я только начинаю изучать чистую архитектуру и буду благодарен за любой совет. У меня есть проект (asp.net), и я собираюсь переписать его на чистую архитектуру. Мне нужно использовать отдельный usecase для каждой crud-операции, например: createThingUseCase, deleteThingUseCase? Я слышал, что у меня должен быть один usecase для одного контроллера. Мне нужно создать контроллер для каждой операции, или я чего-то не понял?
У меня есть контроллер входа и контроллер для регистрации, это понятно. Но у меня есть, например, ThingsController с crud-операциями. Мне надо разделить его на несколько под каждую операцию?

Очень рекомендую почитать блог https://t.me/sh_dotnet/3 там есть пример проекта с чистой архитектурой со всеми нюансами которые возникают

Почитайте про Vertical Slice Architecture, если ещё не знакомы.

Да, для каждой CRUD-операции можно создать отдельный use case, чтобы каждая операция представляла независимую логику. Например:

CreateThingUseCase
ReadThingUseCase
UpdateThingUseCase
DeleteThingUseCase

Каждый use case отвечает за свою уникальную операцию и инкапсулирует логику, связанную с ней, включая проверки прав доступа, валидацию и трансформации данных.
Нет необходимости создавать отдельный контроллер для каждой CRUD-операции. Вы можете использовать один контроллер, например, ThingsController, где каждый метод контроллера вызывает свой use case. То есть, контроллер может остаться общим, а вот операции будут делегированы соответствующим use cases.
Контроллеры должны только обрабатывать HTTP-запросы и отвечать за передачу данных между слоем представления и слоями use cases. Вся бизнес-логика находится в use cases, а контроллеры минимально взаимодействуют с use cases, отправляя данные и получая результаты для формирования ответа.
Каждый use case — это независимый элемент приложения, который легко тестировать и поддерживать. Вы можете использовать use cases так, чтобы они работали как конечные операции (только для одного действия), или разделять общие процессы между use cases, если они имеют схожие задачи.
